# RestClient not found error in rails while deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

I have a method to delete users from my project. For that I used below code.

```
def member_destroy
    begin
      @url = api_version_root+'/users/'+params[:mid]
      response = RestClient.delete @url, api_token_hash

      flash[:info] = "User Deleted"
      redirect_to :back and return
    rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => err
      handle_rest_error http_code: err.http_code
    end
  end
```

But it gives me RestClient::NotFound error. Can anyone help me for this.

Comment: Are you requiring `rest-client` in the file?

Answer (score 0):

This error show that your `@url` return 404 error on request